# How Do I Convert A string to Type Uri (simple)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

What is the quickest way to convert a string value of a URL to type URI in VB.NET?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes.

```
Dim myUri As New Uri("http://www.contoso.com/")
```

Just replace the string with your variable and you should be good to go.

Comment: Dim pUri As New Uri("/praxima/rptZZ-AllParametersReport")
                .ReportServerUrl = pUri

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the string into the constructor.

```
Dim url As String = "http://test.com"
Dim uri As New Uri(url)
```